# Can you Plane Shift to the plane that you're on?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, planes, teleportation

What happens if you cast [*plane shift*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plane-shift) and then attempt to shift to the plane that you're on?  I can think of a few reasons this might happen in-game:

1. For some reason, the PCs don't know what plane they're on, so they try to *plane shift* to their current plane.
2. PCs who don't have *teleport* memorized find themselves in over their heads, and want to use *plane shift* to escape from their current location (but don't actually want to go to another plane).

I can think of a few possible results:

1. The spell functions as normal.  The targets immediately move elsewhere on the same plane, arriving 5 to 500 miles from their intended destination.
2. The spell fails without explanation, so PCs in situation #1 still don't find out what plane they're on.
3. The spell fails, but it is somehow obvious why.  PCs in situation #1 find out that they're already on the plane they were trying to go to.

Are there any possibilities I'm missing?  Has this issue been addressed explicitly in any edition of *D&D* or *Pathfinder*?  What actually happens in *Pathfinder*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### You cannot shift to the plane that you are on.

If you look at the spell description, it's pretty clear about this:

> You move yourself or some other creature to **another** plane of existence or alternate dimension.

Emphasis mine.  The exact same text exists in both 3.5 and Pathfinder.  In order to use *plane shift*, you have to be transporting yourself to a different plane.

This basically works like result 2; if you're on Arcadia, and you try to *plane shift* to Arcadia, it doesn't work.  The most likely reason is that you are trying to shift to a plane you're already on, but you might instead be failing for some other reason: a restriction on planar travel from your current location, some kind of protection on the location you're trying to shift to, or something else.

Comment: Follow-up question here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51832/10642